# How to use the std function on section of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, std, pandas-loc

I am trying to slice the array up when using the std function to only use part of it. That part being 1:t, as t is an integer that grows with each iteration of the for loop. Y is my pandas dataset and the column is 'TempK' which is specified as the column parameter. Is there a limit on much you can slice as the dataset is quite big or is it something else?

```
def calc_std(t, y, column):
    deviationPrediction = np.std(y.loc[1:t, [column]])
    return deviationPrediction
```

The error I receive is this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Kabla\Anaconda3\envs\condaEnv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2657, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(key)
> KeyError: 1

Comment: So t is from 1 : len(df)?

Comment: you can do so more directly: `df.loc[start:end, [columns]].std()`

Comment: yes, it iterates through the whole df. As i call the function from a for loop, t wont always be the end. can i substitute end for t?

Comment: Can you `print(y)` and post the output? it seems to me that there is no row called "1". Maybe y is indexed in a particular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

> note that 5 is interpreted as a label of the index, and never as an
> integer position along the index